# Custom FormHelper templatees

Tags: cakephp-3.0, formhelper

[The CakePHP docs on using the FormHelper](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#customizing-the-templates-formhelper-uses) suggest I should be able to create new templates for its output once, and use this throughout my project.

As described it requires modifying the loading of the FormHelper, from this:

```
$this->loadHelper('Form');
```

to this:

```
$this->loadHelper('Form', [
    'templates' => 'app_form',
]);
```

where app_form refers to a file in the config directory. However, I haven't had to actually load the FormHelper at all, it's magically available already, and if I try to do the above I get an error to the effect the helper has already been loaded:

```
The "Form" alias has already been loaded with the following config: array (...
```

Don't know if the docs are out of sync with the current version of CakePHP, but I can't see how to use this functionality - anyone know?

Comment: Where are you putting this `loadHelper` call?

Comment: Ha, I think I must have been putting it in the wrong place - if I stick it in the initialize method of AppView it works as described - thanks for prompting me to look again!